# How to get individuals all record in php from mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

How can i get all records which are stored in the mysqli database against certain email id.

[image]

Like I want to get all the records of question field which are stored against id@check.com, to get that what i have done so far is mentioned below. but my for loop codes prints only www.google.com. how can i get other two field?

```
<?php
  $email = $_SESSION["email"];
  $prevq = "Select *  FROM `askadoc` WHERE `email` = '$email'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $prevq);
  $prevq = "";
  $location = "";

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $prevq = $row["question"];
      $date = $row["date"];
    }
  }
?>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
  <?php
    for($i=0; $i<=count($email); $i++){
      echo $date;
      echo "<br>";
      echo $prevq;
      echo "<br>";
    }
  ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of "for($i=0; $i<=count($email); $i++)"?

Comment: i tried to use 'for loop' so that it count all the rows of email ( for an example : id@check.com)  and print those rows.

Comment: you assigned $email as string variable so how could is be benificial for you in for loop in for loop count($email) return the length of the assigned mail id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will work:

```
<?php
$email = $_SESSION["email"];
$prevq = "Select *  FROM `askadoc` WHERE `email` = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $prevq);
$prevq = "";
$location = "";

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0):
    ?>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) :
                $prevq = $row["question"];
                $date = $row["date"];

                echo $date;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $prevq;
                echo "<br>";

            endwhile;
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write your `while loop` inside your div

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
    <?php
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          echo $prevq = $row["question"];
          echo $date = $row["date"];
        }
      }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried not working, would you write a bit more details?

Comment: Don't use for loop in that. just use while condition